# Check WatchOS version in switch statement

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos

I have an application using WatchKit and one of the function includes a `switch` statement for checking a `CLKComplicationFamily`, essentially

```
switch complication.family {
case .extraLarge:
  ...
case .circularSmall:
  ...
...
}
```

Some types of `CLKComplicationFamily`, such as `.graphicCorner`, are only available starting WatchOS 5.0. As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62551591/10173483), I decided to use an `#if` compiler control statement to compile some `case`s only if the WatchOS version is at least 5 (otherwise there were complaints from the compiler).

However, as per the [Apple Documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#grammar_conditional-compilation-block), there is only the option to check for WatchOS, not for its exact version.

Therefore: How do I best handle the case where some types I am matching against in a `switch-case` are only available starting from a specific WatchOS version?

I *do* want to support devices with older versions as well, so marking the whole function as `@available` is (at least in my opinion) not the way to go.